# Replace text by focus on enable code by ifdef

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

Does it exist any way to replace only text that is enabled by C preprocessor macro like `#if`/`#ifdef` in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking whether such a capability is built in, the answer is "no."

If you're asking whether it's possible to *create* a way to do it, then depending on how hard you're willing to work, the answer is "maybe." Obviously the editor knows what code is enabled by the preprocessor in a source file, because a scanner runs on it, using the current project settings to find out which preprocessor symbols are defined. That information is used by a colorizer to color the source file. The standard search and replace function, however, ignores that information (and anything else that's not the base text). If you want to badly enough, you can use the Visual Studio SDK to write an extension that implements your own search and replace function, and have it use the scanner output (or possibly, the collection of text adornments created by the colorizer) to guide which parts of the source file to do the search and replace in. That would be a lot of work, probably a lot more than any manual search and replace process. On the other hand, maybe you could sell the resulting extension in the VS Gallery.

The easiest way to do what you want is to do the search and replace with the existing tool, one search at a time (F3 is your friend here), and to make the change only if the text is the "enabled" color.